# How can I beat the browser when it comes to reducing image size?

Tags: gimp, png, eps

Can't get my head around this. I tried several ways to reduce the pixel size of a logo in Gimp. However, the browser (either safari, firefox or chrome on my iMac) is always amazingly better reducing the logo to the size I specify in the html. Is it really so difficult to beat the browser?

For your information: My base file is an .eps. For Gimp to be able to read the file I converted the format to .tif and .png. I need the intermediate step of Gimp because I need to make the background of the image transparent.

Comment: What exactly do you try to be "better" in?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. How is the browser beating Gimp? In perceived quality of the image (when resized)? In that case, how are you actually resizing the image? Would you mind posting some examples?

Comment: @dom: compressed images will always *download* faster. You are conflating downloading with opening, decoding, and rendering the image. Also, PPI is not compression. It is a single-byte flag. Ignoring metadata and any headers, 200x200@96ppi is identical in size to 200x200@192PPI

Comment: @dom: only correcting the terms. It is plausible and likely that compressed images take measurably (in milliseconds) longer to display: decompression is very CPU/GPU dependent. Probably what you read was a 200px square image served as a compressed vs uncompressed.

Comment: Try to find sources that back up your claims and phrase it like those?

Answer (score 1):

The quality of the reduced image depends on the process used, and of course of the original files.

2 things that you can try are:

1) Work in a much higher resolution. For example, if you need a final file of 100x100px work on an image 800x800px and at the end, resample it to the final size.

2) Apply some sharpening on this final size file.

You have to be certain the image is displayed in its real size in your web page, not resized afterwards in the html properties or a css value.

And make sure you are not compressing too much a jpg file. For logos the png format is better option than jpg. But also you can try some vector format like svg.

Comment: Rafael, Thank you for your answer. I did all of this and afterall, the quality differences I mentioned are probably artifacts – I'll com to that below.

Comment: Following your svg-suggestion, I tried that format. However. I don't get it to work inside an <img> element: It only works here if I put it inside an <object> element.

Comment: Regarding the quality differences between rescaling manually and rescaling by the browser I mentioned, that may have been artifacts. What I did was I enlarged the browser to see more closely what the various images looked like. If instead I take screeshots and enlarge those for closer inspection, there are only minor differences.

Comment: Im not sure but I think the render engines of newer browsers do some resampling and sharpening. But sometimes if the browser just reescales the image, without any resampling the image could be sharper, but in some cases, like the hair on a person you can notice a moiré pattern. I have not noticed this pattern on some tests i did, so that is why im asumming they are actually resampling the photos. Im not sure what types of sharpening gimp can do. Try different settings.

Comment: For the svg try the tag <svg> http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_inhtml.asp But before using it you probably need to see if your users can see them without the need of a plugin: http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg

Comment: Regarding my remark about svg not working (i.e. not displayed) when inside an <img> element: this is when the svg is on my isp hosted server. If the svg sits locally on my computer or on some other webistes all is fine/ Mayby it's to do with http headers – what do you think?

Comment: Could be. But probably that speciffic issue is somehow out of scope of the original post, becouse it is more like an html problem, or a server side one. Take a look at this: http://css-tricks.com/svg-fallbacks/ and if it does not work try asking in http://stackoverflow.com/ Retruning to the original question. Did you tried different sharpening settings?

Answer (score 1):

Resize your raster image in several steps. At each step divide the width and height by 2 (or lower) and apply some sharpening.

Answer (score 1):

If the browser truly does it better, resize in HTML and then screen shot it.

Answer (score 1):

Resizing raster images always results in some quality loss. The degree is subjective and scaling up tends to highlight flaws while scaling down is more forgiving.

The browser will render an EPS "scaled down" better than opening it in GIMP and later scaling it down because an EPS is not typically a raster image. It is stored as "math" and only gets rendered to pixels for display. Your browser is "scaling" by plotting the coordinates of the curves at the specific pixel intervals tailor-made for the pixel size specified in your html.

When you open in GIMP and then scale it, you are rasterizing the image for a larger grid size and then later scaling down by averaging pixels. This leads to small errors. The best outcome for you will be to somehow specify the desired final display size when opening the EPS in GIMP so that the curves are plotted especially for that size. If you do need to open it larger than that, then sizes which are powers of 2x the desired size will be the best choice (2x, 4x 8x size).